# FileStream StreamReader problem in C#

Tags: c#

I'm testing how the classes FileStream and StreamReader work togheter. Via a Console application.
I'm trying to go in a file and read the lines and print them on the console.

I've been able to do it with a while-loop, but I want to try it with a foreach loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace testing
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = @"C:\Temp\New Folder\New Text Document.txt";
            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    foreach(string line in file)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I keep getting for this is: Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'

The while loop, which does work, looks like this:

```
while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

I'm probably overlooking something really basic, but I can't see it.

Comment: On the subject of foreach (directly relating to your comment about "yield"), I recommend the free chapter 6 of C# in Depth - here: http://www.manning.com/skeet/

Comment: Your problem is that your code is iterating (foreach) through each element in "file" (which is a string). Therefore each element is a "char".  Hence the compiler error message that you are then trying to convert to the string type.

You should be iterating (foreach) through the data from the stream.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To read all lines in New Text Document.txt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace testing
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = @"C:\Temp\New Folder\New Text Document.txt";
            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {                    
                using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 44):

If you want to read a file line-by-line via foreach (in a reusable fashion), consider the following iterator block:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that this this is lazily evaluated - there is none of the buffering that you would associate with `File.ReadAllLines()`. The `foreach` syntax will ensure that the iterator is `Dispose()`d correctly even for exceptions, closing the file:

```
foreach(string line in ReadLines(file))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

---

(this bit is added just for interest...)

Another advantage of this type of abstraction is that it plays beautifully with LINQ - i.e. it is easy to do transformations / filters etc with this approach:

```
        DateTime minDate = new DateTime(2000,1,1);
        var query = from line in ReadLines(file)
                    let tokens = line.Split('\t')
                    let person = new
                    {
                        Forname = tokens[0],
                        Surname = tokens[1],
                        DoB = DateTime.Parse(tokens[2])
                    }
                    where person.DoB >= minDate
                    select person;
        foreach (var person in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}: born {2}",
                person.Surname, person.Forname, person.DoB);
        }
```

And again, all evaluated lazily (no buffering).

Comment: Since .net 4.0 this is built into the BCL as [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: wouldn't using `while (!reader.EndOfStream) { yield return reader.ReadLine() }` be slightly better performance-wise? Obviously not by a long margin at all, but the variable `line` above is used nowhere other than on the `yield return`, and I personally find the condition more readable this way around.

Answer (score 26):

I have a `LineReader` class in my [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) project. It's slightly more general than the solutions given here, mostly in terms of the way you can construct it:

- From a function returning a stream, in which case it will use UTF-8
- From a function returning a stream, and an encoding
- From a function which returns a text reader
- From just a filename, in which case it will use UTF-8
- From a filename and an encoding

The class "owns" whatever resources it uses, and closes them appropriately. However, it does this without implementing `IDisposable` itself. This is why it takes `Func<Stream>` and `Func<TextReader>` instead of the stream or the reader directly - it needs to be able to defer the opening until it needs it. It's the iterator itself (which is automatically disposed by a `foreach` loop) which closes the resource.

As Marc pointed out, this works really well in LINQ. One example I like to give is:

```
var errors = from file in Directory.GetFiles(logDirectory, "*.log")
             from line in new LineReader(file)
             select new LogEntry(line) into entry
             where entry.Severity == Severity.Error
             select entry;
```

This will stream all the errors from a whole bunch of log files, opening and closing as it goes. Combined with Push LINQ, you can do all kinds of nice stuff :)

It's not a particularly "tricky" class, but it's really handy. Here's the full source, for convenience if you don't want to download MiscUtil. The licence for the source code is [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/licence.txt).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace MiscUtil.IO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads a data source line by line. The source can be a file, a stream,
    /// or a text reader. In any case, the source is only opened when the
    /// enumerator is fetched, and is closed when the iterator is disposed.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class LineReader : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Means of creating a TextReader to read from.
        /// </summary>
        readonly Func<TextReader> dataSource;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a LineReader from a stream source. The delegate is only
        /// called when the enumerator is fetched. UTF-8 is used to decode
        /// the stream into text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="streamSource">Data source</param>
        public LineReader(Func<Stream> streamSource)
            : this(streamSource, Encoding.UTF8)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a LineReader from a stream source. The delegate is only
        /// called when the enumerator is fetched.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="streamSource">Data source</param>
        /// <param name="encoding">Encoding to use to decode the stream
        /// into text</param>
        public LineReader(Func<Stream> streamSource, Encoding encoding)
            : this(() => new StreamReader(streamSource(), encoding))
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a LineReader from a filename. The file is only opened
        /// (or even checked for existence) when the enumerator is fetched.
        /// UTF8 is used to decode the file into text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">File to read from</param>
        public LineReader(string filename)
            : this(filename, Encoding.UTF8)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a LineReader from a filename. The file is only opened
        /// (or even checked for existence) when the enumerator is fetched.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename">File to read from</param>
        /// <param name="encoding">Encoding to use to decode the file
        /// into text</param>
        public LineReader(string filename, Encoding encoding)
            : this(() => new StreamReader(filename, encoding))
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a LineReader from a TextReader source. The delegate
        /// is only called when the enumerator is fetched
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataSource">Data source</param>
        public LineReader(Func<TextReader> dataSource)
        {
            this.dataSource = dataSource;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enumerates the data source line by line.
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            using (TextReader reader = dataSource())
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    yield return line;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enumerates the data source line by line.
        /// </summary>
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! You should put this up in GitHub mate.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in:

```
foreach(string line in file)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Its because the "file" is string, and string implements IEnumerable. But this enumerator returns "char" and "char" can not be implictly converted to string.

You should use the while loop, as you sayd.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more elegant is the following...

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            yield return reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like homework to me ;)

You're iterating over the filename (a string) itself which gives you one character at a time. Just use the while approach that correctly uses sr.ReadLine().

Comment: It's 'kinda' homework. I'm working on something else that contains similar things. So I'm getting to know the FileStream and StreamReader/StreamWriter classes a bit ^^

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `StreamReader` and then trying to find lines inside the `String file` variable, you can simply use `File.ReadAllLines`:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
foreach(string line in lines)
   Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: Not if you're not wanting to lock the file, and the file is way bigger than ram!

Answer (score 0):

You are enumerating a string, and when you do that, you take one char at the time.

Are you sure this is what you want?

```
foreach(string line in file)
```

Comment: Not really what I want, I'm just testing the possibilities. I've never used the foreach-loop much really.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic (not memory efficient) approach of iterating every line in a file is

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(file))
{
  ..
}
```

Comment: See my post for a non-buffering version of this

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want something like this:

```
using ( FileStream fileStream = new FileStream( file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read ) )
{
    using ( StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader( fileStream ) )
    {
        string line = "";
        while ( null != ( line = streamReader.ReadLine() ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( line );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I printed in my first post, just a different pointername for the StreamReader and the != null on the other side of the while loop...

Comment: Well not quite, as mine works, yours doesn't. ;-)

Your problem is that you are doing a "foreach" on the name of the file, not on the stream.