# How to tell two .NET exceptions apart when they share the same type?

Tags: .net, exception

When I encounter:

```
  View Certificate: .\SecurityTool.exe

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the requested object.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertFileType(String fileName)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyS
torageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName)
   at CORSIS.PortFusion.Security.Tool.view@167-1.Invoke(String file) in C:\CORSIS\Software\PortFusion\0.9.3\PortFusionSource\PortFusion\SecurityTool\P
rogram.fs:line 170

   >  Private Key Password
   =  ""
   =  PS C:\CORSIS\Software\PortFusion\0.9.3\PortFusionSource\PortFusion\SecurityTool\bin\Debug> .\SecurityTool certificates view .\go.pfx
CORSIS PortFusion : Distributed Reverse Proxy Security Tool 0.9.8.0



  View Certificate: .\go.pfx

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySe
t, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyS
torageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName)
   at CORSIS.PortFusion.Security.Tool.view@167-1.Invoke(String file) in C:\CORSIS\Software\PortFusion\0.9.3\PortFusionSource\PortFusion\SecurityTool\P
rogram.fs:line 170

   >  Private Key Password
   =  ""
   =  PS C:\CORSIS\Software\PortFusion\0.9.3\PortFusionSource\PortFusion\SecurityTool\bin\Debug>
```

How can I tell the two instance of System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException apart?

**Note:** exception texts get localized so I cannot match on them as descriptions would be different on German, Chinese machines etc.

Comment: The `Message` would be different for the different types - you will have to have localized versions of the test though :(

Comment: You could also compare the `.StackTrace`s and check for e.g. _LoadCertFromFile

Comment: See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptographicexception.aspx, maybe you can differentiate by error code or inner exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test it but Exception.HResult property looks promising: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult.aspx)

Comment: HResult is protected and these exceptions are thrown by system classes. I can do reflection to see if they differ in my case though.

Comment: See the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991537/how-do-i-determine-the-hresult-for-a-system-io-ioexception, it uses `Marshal.GetHRForException`

Comment: Interesting approach with the `Marshal` class -- although this has side effects that might be undesirable (setting the COM `IErrorInfo` data for the calling thread).

Answer (score 3):

You are right to avoid using message strings programmatically to differentiate exceptions. Your best bets to differentiate exceptions that use the same type are the following:

- The [`Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) dictionary; this is not used all that often, but you can check if there are any data values that differ between the types.
- The [`InnerException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) type (if there is one).

The [`HResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult.aspx) value is useful but is not accessible (it is a `protected` property -- you would need reflection to read it). It also tends to be the same value for the same exception type.

I should point out that more often than not, if two exceptions have the same runtime type, they are generally expected to be handled the same way. Evaluate if you *really* need to handle them differently.

Answer (score 0):

Their `Message` properties will be different.

Comment: Are they not localized? Am I supposed to check all the languages of the world?