# How can I tell if an IOException is caused by the fact that another process uses that file?

Tags: c#, .net, process, io, ioexception

Let's take this code sample :

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            var trimChars = new[] { '"' };
            var path = Environment.CommandLine.Trim().Trim(trimChars);
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

running this (the program tries to overwrite itself) causes an exception to be thrown :

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
Message=The process cannot access the file 'F:\TEMP\ConsoleApplication25\ConsoleApplication25\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication25.vshost.exe' because it is being used by another process.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String path, Byte[] bytes)
   at ConsoleApplication25.Program.Main() in F:\TEMP\ConsoleApplication25\ConsoleApplication25\Program.cs:line 13
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

.. which is expected and obvious. **HOWEVER**, the instance of the IOException doesn't offer me any **reliable** information that I can use **programatically** to detect that the file is in use by another process. Just the `Message` property tells you this, but this depends on the local culture so I can't rely on it.

Any idea how to deal with this? I need to take a special action if the file is in use by another process but I can't find a way to separate this case from other (exceptional) cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question is possible a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9293227/21567) one,  more so the answer here is pretty close to the [accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294382/21567). However, there is some notable difference about the error codes to check. You might consider, eventually, upvoting the answer to the other question.

You could do as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294382/21567) answer, but check for `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` (0x20)

```
const long ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION = 0x20;
const long ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION = 0x21;

//Only for .NET <4.5: long win32ErrorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(ex) & 0xFFFF;
long win32ErrorCode = ex.HResult & 0xFFFF; // .NET 4.5+
if (win32ErrorCode == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION || win32ErrorCode == ERROR_LOCK_VIOLATION )
{
    // file in use.
}
```

However, mind you that using `GetHRForException` has [side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294382/21567) you may not want to have.

**Update** As commenter @jmn2 pointed out, since .NET 4.5 the [`Exception.HResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.exception.hresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property is now public. So there is no need for using `GetHRForException` - unless you need to support pre 4.5 code, of course.

To write a "wrapper" that is runtime-backwards compatible you should invoke `HResult` via reflection because (provided you use `GetProperties` with `BindingFlags.Public` *and* `BindingFlags.NonPublic`) that will work with all versions of the .NET framework (see [this very much related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294422/21567)).

Comment: @Christian.K If you use .NET 4.5 or higher, `ex.HResult` is available and much better than the side-effect-ridden `GetHRForException`.

Comment: @jnm2 yes, of course. Thanks for pointing out (at the time .NET 4.5 was not available and I haven't revisited the question since then ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Here is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293227/how-to-check-if-ioexception-is-not-enough-disk-space-exception-type)

You will need to check HResult of exception. And then check its value:

```
int hr = Marshal.GetHRForException( ex );
```

Here is code for [sharing violation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION) of lock violation

Comment: interesting! I didn't know this trick :D However I'm getting -2147024864 as the HResult...

Comment: Try this: long hr = Marshal.GetHRForException(ex) & 0xFFFF; (as in link)

Comment: @AndreiRinea That HRESULT is actually `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` (-2147024864 & 0xffff = 0x20). See my answer or [the original one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9294382/21567) for more details.