# Why is the getter for Exception.HResult no longer protected?

Tags: c#, exception, hresult

As of .NET 4.5, the getter for [`Exception.HResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sh5cw61c(v=vs.110).aspx) is now `public`, but it used to be `protected`.

From MSDN:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the HResult property's setter is protected, whereas its getter is public. In previous versions of the .NET Framework, both getter and setter are protected.

Do we know why this change was made?

Comment: It seems like an oversight that it hadn't been done earlier which they now rectified. At least it makes sense to me that it's public rather than protected.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel A [13-year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_1.0) oversight! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In .NET 4.5, the `HResult` property getter is now `Public`, so you do not have to use `Marshal.GetHRForException` (along with its side affects) anymore.

Source: [How to check if IOException is Not-Enough-Disk-Space-Exception type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293227/how-to-check-if-ioexception-is-not-enough-disk-space-exception-type/22763264#22763264)