# How to catch specific OleDbException?

Tags: .net, exception, oledbconnection, hresult

I need to catch the following specific exception:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was caught   ErrorCode=-2147467259
>   Message="The changes you requested to the table were not successful
>   because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key,
>   or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain
>   duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit
>   duplicate entries and try again."   Source="Microsoft JET Database
>   Engine"   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>          at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

I'm not sure what `ErrorCode` is but it looks unreliable.

Can I rely on `Message` being identical across platforms?

Can I somehow use the `OleDbHResult hr` value found in the stack trace?  (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/991660/327528)

Is the only solution to do a text search of `Message` for words like `duplicate` and `primary key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JET error code for a `OleDbException` can be found from:

```
OleDbError.SQLState
```

which is `3022` for the exception provided in the question.

Answer (score 7):

You're right that the ErrorCode (-2147467259 = 0x80004005 = E_FAIL) is too generic, and relying on the message is very fragile - e.g. consider localization.

I would look at the `OleDbException.Errors` collection to try to find something more specific.

Comment: What about `OleDbHResult hr` ?

Comment: @CJ7 - if you look at `System.Data.dll` with Reflector, you'll see the definition of the internal enum `OleDbhResult`.  From what I can see it's the same as `ErrorCode` = E_FAIL, i.e. non-specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `SQLState` property for each error in the `OleDbException.Errors` collection

Found this reference:
[SQL State Error Codes](http://www.rosam.se/doc/atsdoc/Server%20-%20Messages%20and%20Codes/ADC5906BBD514757BAEE546DC6F7A4FA/0.htm) <- Not working anymore
Updated reference: [SQL error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-error-messages)

Comment: not found http://www.rosam.se/doc/atsdoc/Server%20-%20Messages%20and%20Codes/ADC5906BBD514757BAEE546DC6F7A4FA/0.htm

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
} catch (OleDbException ex) {
  if (ex.ErrorCode == -2147467259) {
    MessageBox.Show("Hi , yes");
  }
}
```