# IOException raised despite IOException catch block

Tags: c#, .net

We have a Windows Forms application which connects to some web services. It lists the documents in the system, and when the user double-clicks one we download the file to the local computer and open the document for them to edit. Once the user closes the document then we upload it back to the system.

For this process we have been monitoring the file lock on the document. As soon as the file lock is released we upload the document.

The `IsFileLocked` method looks like this:

```
private const int ErrorLockViolation = 33;
private const int ErrorSharingViolation = 32;

private static bool IsFileLocked(string fileName)
{
    Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName));

    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
            {
                fs.ReadByte();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // get the HRESULT for this exception
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(ex) & 0xFFFF;

        return errorCode == ErrorSharingViolation || errorCode == ErrorLockViolation;
    }
}
```

We call this in a loop with a 5 second sleep between attempts. This seems to work great most of the time but occasionally we see an `IOException` from this method. I cannot see how it is possible for this exception to be thrown.

The exception is:

```
IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\redacted\AppData\Roaming\redacted\Jobs\09c39a4c-c1a3-4bb9-a5b5-54e00bb6c747\4b5c4642-8ede-4881-8fa9-a7944852d93e\CV abcde abcdef.docx' because it is being used by another process.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
at redacted.Helpers.IsFileLocked(String fileName)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(Guid& rclsid, IntPtr reserved, Object& ppunk)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(String progID)
at redacted.OutlookHelper.GetOutlookInternal()
at redacted.OutlookHelper.GetOutlook()
...
```

The other odd part is the stack trace. This refers to `GetOutlook` which is a different part of the system entirely (unrelated to document handling). There are two code paths into `IsFileLocked` and neither are reachable via the `GetOutlookInternal` method. It is almost as if the stack is getting corrupt.

**Why not use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?**

As a side-note, we did consider using a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor file changes but discounted this approach because the user may keep the document open and continue making further changes to it. Our web services unlock the document as soon as we upload it so we cannot do that until the user has completed finished with it.

We are only concerned with documents that are locked by their application. I appreciate there are some applications which do not lock their files but we do not need to consider them here.

**The Outlook methods**

Below is the `GetOutlookInternal` method that appears in the stack - as you can see, it is only dealing with Outlook Interop and is unrelated to the document opening. It does not call into `IsFileLocked`:

```
    private static Application GetOutlookInternal()
    {
        Application outlook;

        // Check whether there is an Outlook process running.
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                // If so, use the GetActiveObject method to obtain the process and cast it to an Application object.
                outlook = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode == -2147221021)    // HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE)
                {
                    // Outlook is running but not ready (not in Running Object Table (ROT) - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238610)
                    outlook = CreateOutlookSingleton();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If not running, create a new instance of Outlook and log on to the default profile.
            outlook = CreateOutlookSingleton();
        }
        return outlook;
    }

    private static Application CreateOutlookSingleton()
    {
        Application outlook = new Application();

        NameSpace nameSpace = null;
        Folder folder = null;
        try
        {
            nameSpace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");

            // Create an instance of the Inbox folder. If Outlook is not already running, this has the side
            // effect of initializing MAPI. This is the approach recommended in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861594(v=office.15).aspx
            folder = (Folder)nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        }
        finally
        {
            Helpers.ReleaseComObject(ref folder);
            Helpers.ReleaseComObject(ref nameSpace);
        }

        return outlook;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you debug and walk through the stack trace? This seems rather odd, and I doubt the stack trace would be corrupt (with an `IOException` at least)... can you post the code for `GetOutlookInternal`?

Comment: It is never a good idea to share files in windows.   It looks like you are using outlook to access files.  I think oledb is being used to by outlook to access the files.  Oledb is not designed to operate in a multi-user environment and doesn't properly handle locking of files.  Even though you may think you are locking the files in c#, you are only preventing two processes from simultaneously access the files.  it doesn't mean that another windows process can't access the file.  Are you using any Async processes?

Comment: @Jcl unfortunately the issue only occurs on some client PCs, and even then is sporadic. I cannot reproduce in the debugger. I've updated to include the Outlook method.

Comment: @jdweng I am not using Outlook to access files - the application does many things, some are Outlook related and some are file related. There is no code path from GetOutlookInternal() to IsFileLocked() as can be seen in my edit.

Comment: This looks really weird. If you are not using threading, or unsafe code, my only idea is your exception logging code could be bogus, but this is a rather off assumption

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I accidentally stumbled across this article which helped to find the cause of my issue: [Marshal.GetHRForException does more than just Get-HR-For-Exception](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yizhang/2013/01/18/marshal-gethrforexception-does-more-than-just-get-hr-for-exception/)

It turns out we had two threads, one was calling [`Marshal.GetHRForException(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gethrforexception(v=vs.110).aspx) on an `IOException` to determine if a file is locked (Win32 error code 32 or 33). Another thread was calling [`Marshal.GetActiveObject(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject(v=vs.110).aspx) to connect to an Outlook instance using Interop.

If `GetHRForException` is called first, and then `GetActiveObject` is called second but throws a `COMException`, then you get completely the wrong exception and stack trace. This is because `GetHRForException` is effectively "setting" the exception and `GetActiveObject` will throw that instead of the real `COMException`.

**Example code to reproduce:**

This issue can be reproduced using the following code. Create a new console application, import the Outlook COM reference, and paste in the code. Ensure Outlook is not running when you start the application:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool isLocked = IsFileLocked();
        Console.WriteLine("IsLocked = " + isLocked);
        ShowOutlookWindow();
    }

    private static bool IsFileLocked()
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\path\to\non_existant_file.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
            {
                fs.ReadByte();
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(ex) & 0xFFFF;
            return errorCode == 32 || errorCode == 33; // lock or sharing violation
        }
    }

    private static void ShowOutlookWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            Application outlook = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application"); 
            // ^^ causes COMException because Outlook is not running
            MailItem mailItem = outlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Display();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

You would expect to see the `COMException` in the console, but this is what you see

```
IsLocked = False
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\path\to\non_existant_file.docx'.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
    at System.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
    at MyProject.Program.IsFileLocked()
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(Guid& rclsid, IntPtr reserved, Object& ppunk)
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(String progID)
    at MyProject.Program.ShowOutlookWindow()
```

Note how the exception is `DirectoryNotFoundException`, and the stack incorrectly suggests `GetActiveObject` called into `IsFileLocked`.

**Solution:**

The solution to this problem was simply to use the [`Exception.HResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead of `GetHRForException`. Previously this property was protected but it is now accessible since we upgraded the project to .NET 4.5

```
private static bool IsFileLocked()
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\path\to\non_existant_file.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            fs.ReadByte();
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        int errorCode = ex.HResult & 0xFFFF;
        return errorCode == 32 || errorCode == 33; // lock or sharing violation
    }
}
```

With this change, the behaviour is as expected. The console now shows:

```
IsLocked = False
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800401E3): Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(Guid& rclsid, IntPtr reserved, Object& ppunk)
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(String progID)
    at MyProject.Program.ShowOutlookWindow()
```

***TL;DR:*** Don't use `Marshal.GetHRForException` if you are also using COM components.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with a solution. I have seen a similar thing so my code now looks like: `int errorCode = (int)typeof(IOException).InvokeMember("HResult", BindingFlags.GetProperty|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Public, null, ex, null);`