# How to read excel file which is already open by another user in C#.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, c#-4.0

I have an excel file which is already open by another user. Please help me out how to read it.
I have tried by using following code with **READONLY=TRUE** in C#, but yet it dint solve my issue.

```
string stringConExcelMat = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\\PER_Sample\\Input\\6787GHHDSGioSack_v02.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;READONLY=TRUE""";


DataTable TTable = new DataTable("TABLEMAT");
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(stringConExcelMat))
{
     conn.Open();
     using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Raw_Data$A:T]", conn))
     {
         da.Fill(TTable);
     }
}
DataRow RowValues = TTable.Rows[1];
```

Comment: Well, I don't know what you're doing, but if you have a need for many users to use one data source, then I suggest Excel is not the way to go. Use a database instead (e.g. Access, SQL Server, Mysql, Postgresql...).

Comment: Well, I think you won't be able to solve, since Excel requires a lock on the file. Have you tried first to copy the file and read the copied file? You can also try to use [FileStream and FileShare enum](http://stackoverflow.com/a/898017/702048) (that it should be the best solution).

Comment: I have tried using SQL Server too. it is not possible in SQL.

Comment: You better use FileStream for readonly. check this url: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16210/Excel-Reader