# File.ReadAllLines() fails to read from a file that is opened by Excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, file.readalllines

Say I open a file in Excel, I know I cannot write anything to it as it will be "locked" by Excel.

But can I read it? Or that's not possible as well?

I'm using the following code:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(file) Then
    output = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList
    If unique Then
        output = output.Distinct.ToList
    End If
Else
    output = New Generic.List(Of String)
End If
```

How to make it work?

Can I open the file read-only in Excel? Will that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to be aware of the following points:

- Whenever a file is open by a process/thread, the process/thread can either access the file for reading only, writing only, or for both. Check the [`FileAccess` Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileaccess) for more info.
- Also, the process/thread can specify whether the access to the file is shared or not (e.g., shared for reading only, for writing only, for both, or no shared access at all). Check the [`FileShare` Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare) for more.
- If the other process doesn't share access to the file at all, then you wouldn't be able to access the file whether it's for reading or writing.

Now AFAIK, Excel does share the file access *for reading*, (but it doesn't share for writing). So, in order to be able to access the file while it's open by Excel, you need to do the following:

- Open the file for reading *only* (since you don't have access to write).
- Allow access to the file for both reading and writing *since the other process (i.e., Excel) needs to have both*.

The thing is, although `File.ReadAllLines()` opens the file for reading only, it does ***not*** share the access to the file *for writing* (only for reading). To clarify more, `File.ReadAllLines()` uses a [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader) internally <sup>1</sup>, which *--also internally--* uses a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream) with the following values by default: <sup>2</sup>

```
New FileStream(path, 
               FileMode.Open,
               FileAccess.Read,     ' This is good.
               FileShare.Read,      ' This is the problem (see the code below).
               ' ...
```

Which works unless the file is open by another process *that requires write access to the file*. Therefore, you need to create a `FileStream` and set the appropriate values for `FileAccess` and `FileShare` Enums. So, your code should look something like this:

```
Dim output As New List(Of String)
If IO.File.Exists(file) Then
    Using fs As New IO.FileStream(file,
                                  IO.FileMode.Open,
                                  IO.FileAccess.Read,       ' Open for reading only.
                                  IO.FileShare.ReadWrite)   ' Allow access for read/write.
        Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(fs)
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                Dim currentLine As String = reader.ReadLine()
                If unique AndAlso output.Contains(currentLine) Then Continue While
                output.Add(currentLine)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End If
```

Hope that helps.

---

**References:**

<sup>1</sup> [`InternalReadAllLines()` source.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,675b2259e8706c26)

<sup>2</sup> [StreamReader internal constructor source.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,fc51cfc8975d71a1)

Comment: Actually `File.ReadAllLines` does open the file for reading only, but it doesn't share access to the file for writing _(and this is the problem)_. Internally, it uses a `FileStream` with `FileShare.Read` instead of `FileShare.ReadWrite` (that's by default). Therefore, you need to create your own `FileStream` with the appropriate values as explained in the answer. BTW, I've edited the answer and added more information in answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

most likely the other program which has locked the file, has not allowed other programs to do this.  If this is the case, not much you can do :/

Check out this SO which explains in more detail: [How do I open an already opened file with a .net StreamReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897796/how-do-i-open-an-already-opened-file-with-a-net-streamreader)

If you were the program which was opening it in the first place, you could open it in a way that would allow others to open :)