# C#: Looping through lines of multiline string

Tags: c#, loops, multilinestring

What is a good way to loop through each line of a multiline string without using much more memory (for example without splitting it into an array)?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I suggest using a combination of `StringReader` and my `LineReader` class, which is part of [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) but also available in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286533/filestream-streamreader-problem-in-c/286598#286598) - you can easily copy just that class into your own utility project. You'd use it like this:

```
string text = @"First line
second line
third line";

foreach (string line in new LineReader(() => new StringReader(text)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Looping over all the lines in a body of string data (whether that's a file or whatever) is so common that it shouldn't require the calling code to be testing for null etc :) Having said that, if you *do* want to do a manual loop, this is the form that I typically prefer over Fredrik's:

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(input))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Do something with the line
    }
}
```

This way you only have to test for nullity once, and you don't have to think about a do/while loop either (which for some reason always takes me more effort to read than a straight while loop).

Comment: Looks like MiscUtil doesn't have a version for .NET Core.

Comment: @void.pointer: No, it doesn't I'm afraid. It's not a project I'been putting any time into over the last 10 years.

Comment: StringReader, an object little be know it. Thanks. That was What I need.

Answer (score 86):

You can use a [`StringReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) to read a line at a time:

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(input))
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (line != null)
        {
            // do something with the line
        }

    } while (line != null);
}
```

Comment: Great; +1; this helped; but I just want to add that one does not actually need to use the "using" block because there aren't any resources to close in this case.  See [remarks in StringReader article at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Answer (score 26):

I know this has been answered, but I'd like to add my own answer:

```cs
using (var reader = new StringReader(multiLineString))
{
    for (string line = reader.ReadLine(); line != null; line = reader.ReadLine())
    {
        // Do something with the line
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how concise this is.  ty.

Answer (score 9):

from MSDN for [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx)

```
    string textReaderText = "TextReader is the abstract base " +
        "class of StreamReader and StringReader, which read " +
        "characters from streams and strings, respectively.\n\n" +

        "Create an instance of TextReader to open a text file " +
        "for reading a specified range of characters, or to " +
        "create a reader based on an existing stream.\n\n" +

        "You can also use an instance of TextReader to read " +
        "text from a custom backing store using the same " +
        "APIs you would use for a string or a stream.\n\n";

    Console.WriteLine("Original text:\n\n{0}", textReaderText);

    // From textReaderText, create a continuous paragraph 
    // with two spaces between each sentence.
    string aLine, aParagraph = null;
    StringReader strReader = new StringReader(textReaderText);
    while(true)
    {
        aLine = strReader.ReadLine();
        if(aLine != null)
        {
            aParagraph = aParagraph + aLine + " ";
        }
        else
        {
            aParagraph = aParagraph + "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Modified text:\n\n{0}", aParagraph);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using String.Split Method:

```
string text = @"First line
second line
third line";

foreach (string line in text.Split('\n'))
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick code snippet that will find the first non-empty line in a string:

```
string line1;
while (
    ((line1 = sr.ReadLine()) != null) &&
    ((line1 = line1.Trim()).Length == 0)
)
{ /* Do nothing - just trying to find first non-empty line*/ }

if(line1 == null){ /* Error - no non-empty lines in string */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I think we can overcomplicate the solution just to avoid repeating one line of code. This is the reason I landed on this question in the first place.

After thinking about it for a bit I came to the conclusion that the simplest solution is to repeat the `ReadLine` before and inside the loop.

```
using (var stringReader = new StringReader(input))
{
    var line = await stringReader.ReadLineAsync();

    while (line != null)
    {
        // do something
        line = await stringReader.ReadLineAsync();
    }
}
```

I realize this might be considered to not follow the DRY principle, but I think it's worth considering given the simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateLines(this string source)
{
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);

  using StringReader reader = new StringReader(source);

  while(reader.ReadLine() is { } line)
  {
    yield return line;
  }
}
```