# How to loop over lines from a TextReader?

Tags: c#, .net, textreader

How do I loop over lines from a [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) `source`?

I tried

```
foreach (var line in source)
```

But got the error

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.IO.TextReader' because 'System.IO.TextReader' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286533/filestream-streamreader-problem-in-c-sharp

Comment: Or even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271225/c-sharp-reading-a-file-line-by-line too.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
string line;
while ((line = myTextReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    DoSomethingWith(line);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. First time seeing assignment and check at the same time in a loop like this; I wouldn't have thought of doing it this way.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `File.ReadLines` which is *deferred execution* method, then loop thru lines:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("test.txt"))
{
}
```

More information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this code - based on `ReadLine method`

```
        string line = null;
        System.IO.TextReader readFile = new StreamReader("...."); //Adjust your path
        while (true)
        {
            line = readFile.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
            {
                break;    
            }
            MessageBox.Show (line);
        }
        readFile.Close();
        readFile = null;
```