# How to loop over each line from a TextReader?

Tags: c#, .net, textreader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Reading a File Line By Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271225/c-sharp-reading-a-file-line-by-line)
>   [How to loop over lines from a TextReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687453/how-to-loop-over-lines-from-a-textreader)

I am given a .NET [TextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) (a class that can read a sequential series of characters). How can I loop over its content by line?

Comment: Note that given a `TextReader` you cannot be sure that you actually read "all" lines. If someone calls any of the `Read*()` methods before passing you the reference, you won't know. Whether that is an issue, YMMV.

Comment: My answer would be the same as [last time you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687453/how-to-loop-over-lines-from-a-textreader/12687525#12687525)

Comment: I wonder why it was so difficult to find it in the docs: [`TextReader.ReadLine` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
string line = null;
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
{
    // do something with line
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an extension method very easily so that you can use `foreach`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(this TextReader reader)
{
    string line = null;
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

Note that this *won't* close the reader for you at the end.

You can then use:

```
foreach (string line in reader.ReadLines())
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, this is lazy. It will only read a line at a time, rather than reading all the lines into memory.

Comment: Don't you mean `yield return line`? Is this... copied from another anwswer? 8-o

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, I did mean that. And yes, I copied the boilerplaet bit :)

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: Yes, this is lazy - now I've added the yield return properly!

Comment: I'm loving the duality of "lazy" here :p

Comment: nice. though I think one of the readline's missing an s.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata: Where? The one *in the method* is meant to just read a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use it like this:

```
string line;
while ((line = myTextReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //do whatever with "line";
}
```

**OR**

```
string Myfile = @"C:\MyDocument.txt";
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(Myfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{                    
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-lazy solution I have at the moment:

```
foreach(string line in source.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine.ToArray(),StringSplitOptions.None))
```

Comment: Why don't you put this in your original question?